# Can't remove layout margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm attempting to make the content of a menu (header picture) go edge to edge as per the material design guidelines

I am unable to remove a margin around the menu layout.

Things I have tried

1. setting relative layout background as mipmap image
2. removing padding set in the dimensions resource
3. Adding an image directly below the relative layout in an imageview
4. Created a bitmap resource and used the scale property
5. Tried different images
6. Encased the image in a frame layout

Non of which are working . I am providing a screen shot for a better understanding

[image: screenahot]

code the the layouts 
here is activity_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/tool_bar">
        </include>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_frame_menu"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>



    </LinearLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"

        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

header_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:text="Akash Bangad"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="akash.bangad93@gmail.com"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"

            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_profil"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/circleView"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

row_item_menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rowIcon"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/rowText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You might want to show your layout and any code you used to build this

Comment: Are you sure the image is large enough to fill the width?

Comment: change background to any color for checking is there any issue in image or not.

Comment: I should have said. I tried setting a cor and it does edge to edge. However I've tried 3 different images each 1000px wide and it doesn't go any further

Comment: Pls. try in header_menu instead of "@mipmap/ic_launcher" put some color as background (#c3c3c3, for example) and tell if something changes.

Comment: when i set a colour it goes edge to edge

Comment: can u pls try to set another picture, for example, http://e2ua.com/WDF-1038593.html. When I set this picture, everything is fine.

Comment: ive just found that android studio has added a transparent margin to the image on import. This is not something that is present on the original image. Does anyone know ho i can stop this?

Comment: Can you share your original image somewhere?

Comment: http://oxygennacdn3.oxygenna.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/18.jpg

Comment: ive just re-imported the image being sure to tick the Trim image setting on import and this has not resolved the issue.

Comment: Please check my answer :) some stupid tricks from Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems I've got this.
You added an image via Asset Studio, right? I don't know the reason, but it really adds blank space around the image.

The solution worked for me in this case was to place image into `/drawable` folder (in explorer).
Not it looks good.

**Update.** Found the reason - following [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/help/image-asset-studio.html):

> Image Asset Studio generates the following asset types:
>
> Launcher icons.
>  Action bar and tab icons.
>  Notification
>   icons.

So it would not help you to make mipmap from your image in order to use it as background.

Comment: Any suggestions on something that can automatically make the mipmap. A quick Google revealed some untrustworthy software

Comment: You can also put your image into mipmap folder in explorer. I've tried it right now - it works.

Comment: And if you need different picture resolutions - I usually use xnView (great free program) to change image size; it's very easy to use.

Comment: ive added it to the drawables folder and changed the background setting within the hreder_menu. Now i am seeing no image at all, just white, any ideas?

Comment: im getting this error in the logcat Error while loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin

Comment: I used this method to import the image however I had issues with the background setting showing blank. I ended up setting an image view in a frame and set the scale to fitxy . I also cleaned and synced my gradle just in case. All working now

Comment: I did not import the image. I opened /drawable folder in Explorer (right click - show in explorer), put image there. In Android Studio right click - "Synchronize selected files" on /drawable folder. Then in background android:background="@drawable/your_name"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to wrap the **header_menu**'s linear layout with relative layout? Something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="178dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            ...
            <!-- another views -->

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just tried and not working, no change on either margin

Answer (score 0):

Just update your activity_menu's DrawerLayout elevation

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/tool_bar">
    </include>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_frame_menu"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: i have just tried this and it has not worked, i think the problem lies with the transparent margin i have just found on the image (see above for details). Thankyou for your time on this